# Spinful time reversal and SOC

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, representation-theory, spinors, time-reversal-symmetry

I'm having some trouble with understanding the distinction between spinful and spinless time-reversal in a real materials context.

1) Does spinful time-reversal (e.g. $\mathcal{T}^2 = -1$) imply spin-orbit coupling (SOC)?

2) If so, does having $\mathcal{T}^2=-1$ automatically imply that we have to consider the double group of rotations, e.g. that the rotations act on spin and orbital degrees of freedom (like if we had SOC).

3) Finally, if so, is $s_z$ still a good quantum number?

To illustrate these points (feel free to ignore this if the question is clear), say we have spins along the $\hat{z}$-direction (represented by $|\pm\rangle$), and have some combined $C_n\mathcal{T}$ symmetry, where $C_n$ is an $n$-fold rotation with axis $\hat{z}$ and $\mathcal{T}$ is spinful time-reversal. Then the standard spin-rotation formula would suggest that $\mathcal{T}C_n$ acts on spins according to:
$$
\mathcal{T}C_n |\pm \rangle =i\sigma_y\mathcal{K}\exp\left(-i\frac{2\pi}{n} \hat{S}_z\right)|\pm\rangle = i\sigma_y \mathcal{K}\exp\left(\mp i\frac{\pi}{n}\right)|\pm\rangle = \mp \exp\left(\pm i\frac{\pi}{n}\right)|\mp\rangle^*
$$
However, it is not clear to me that the phase factor $\exp\left(\pm i \frac{\pi}{n}\right)$ from the double group *necessarily* has to be there for $\mathcal{T}^2=-1$, and if this calculation even makes sense in the context of double groups/SOC as it assumes $s_z$ to be a good quantum number.

Any help is greatly appreciated!